# How to unit test an entity is targeting the correct DBMS table

Tags: jpa, junit, entity

I have the following entity and it was not until run time that i realized that the table name annotation is incorrect.

How can i write unit tests to prevent this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cache_server")
public class VirtualMachine implements Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not about unit testing here, but rather about integration testing, as you need a JPA provider to test it (with a DB server). And when it comes to integration tests, it is very specific to what technologies you use. If you are in Application Server, like Jboss, take a look at Arquillian.

**UPDATE**

Although I think that usually you do not want to *unit test* values in annotations, as they represent configuration data, you can always read the values in the annotations using some [reflexion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29#Java). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908771/how-to-get-class-annotation-in-java) (directly in the question) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How is this integration testing and not unit testing? Just wanted to know how you categorized this use case. Thanks.

Comment: I already wrote that: it depends on a Database & JPA provider, which are external dependencies.

Comment: Right.. and what do you say if i were to unit test by checking if the Table annotation name attribute == 'virtual_machine'?

Comment: Do you want to say that there are reserved keywords in JPA, like 'virtual_machine', for the `name` property in the `@Table` annotation? What exactly do you want to test in that annotation: that there is such a table in the Database and that its schema is valid? You can always use some reflexion in order to get the `name` value for that annotation, but I do not understand the reason for that.

Comment: I want to ensure that the Entity class is referencing the correct DBMS table name. As you see from the question, its a human error (copy/paste). So i want tests to avoid this.

Comment: Updated the answer, with some references on how to read that value.