# java class.getAnnotation(Class<?> class) returns null

Tags: java, reflection, osgi, classloader

I have written an annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
/**
 * @author christian
 *
 */
public @interface HeraklesObject {

}
```

I use it in an osgi environment (eclipse oxygen with tycho) in a bundle.
In another bundle (a test fragment to be specific) i check classes from the first bundle for this annotation, using:

```
class.getAnnotation(HeraklesObject.class)
```

I am sure, that the queried class has this annotation, but I get always null result.

The retention policy seems right to me, but I am not sure if a class loader issue is present and I don't know how I check this. Or do you see another cause? Thanks
Christian

Comment: Can you please post the complete class that is annotated and the code where exactly you're trying to access said classes annotations

Comment: Also have you tried to remove the compiled `.class` file and recompiling it?

Comment: Have  you tried listing all annotations with `getAnnotations()`?

Comment: @Lino: Yes that was it. Remove compiled .class and recompiling it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
```

Also from [How to get class annotation in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908771/how-to-get-class-annotation-in-java)

use

```
Class newClass = X.class;

for (Annotation annotation : newClass.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
    System.out.println(annotation.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the bundle with the class whose runtime annotations you want to check contain or import the package with the HeraklesObject annotation class?

A class loader will load a class and, if the class of a runtime annotation class is not visible, just ignore the annotation. So you end up with a silent "failure". So check to make sure the package holding the runtime annotation is visible to the bundle holding the annotated class.

If you use Bnd to build the bundle, it should properly import the runtime annotation's package.