# How to process annotations on synthetic elements

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

How can I process annotations on synthetic elements? `RoundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith` doesn't seem to return any synthetic elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what synthetic elements are, but I do know about annotations. Reflections would be your ticket for acquiring annotations from: class, method, or variable in java. Then you can do whatever it is you'd like from it. This is a good example [How to get class annotation in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908771/how-to-get-class-annotation-in-java)

Basically you'll need to get the Class, which contains your var, then locate the var and use getAnnotations method.

```
Clazz z = MyClass.class;
Field[] f = z.getDeclaredFields();
f[0].setAccessible(true);
Annotation[] a = f[0].getAnnotations ();
```

// Then stuff

Comment: Synthetic elements are elements generated by the compiler that you normally can't access in source code. 
Your solution doesn't work for several reasons: 
- It uses runtime reflection but I need to do compile-time annotation processing
- It assumes that you already have a class object to go off. My first idea was to recurse the element tree manually instead of using `RoundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith` but there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to get all the root elements because `Processor.process` is only called if there are supported annotations present on non-synthetic elements