# How to get annotations of the class provided?

Tags: java, annotations

I write `AnnotationsUtil` class. This class should provide methods for detecting annotations of a class. Task is

Implement the getFieldsContainingAnnotations method that lists the names of the fields declared in the object. The list should include all the fields containing at least one annotation. Fields inherited from parent classes should be omitted.
This is my try

```
class AnnotationsUtil {
public static String[] GetStringArray(ArrayList<String> arr)
{
    // declaration and initialise String Array
    String str[] = new String[arr.size()];

    // ArrayList to Array Conversion
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {

        // Assign each value to String array
        str[j] = arr.get(j);
    }

    return str;
}
public static String[] getFieldsContainingAnnotations(Object object) {
    Class cl = object.getClass();
    ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : cl.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getDeclaredAnnotations().length > 0) {
            fields.add(field.getName());
        }
    }
    String[] retArray = GetStringArray(fields);
    return retArray;
}
```

}

Comment: How do you know something is wrong with your method? As far as I can tell, it should return an array with a single non-null element whose value is `"value"` since that's the only field in `String` that has an annotation with a `RetentionPolicy` of `RUNTIME`, at least in Java 14. Though that's ignoring other problems, such as using a fixed-size array instead of a resizable `List` to collect field names.

Comment: Problem is that I study in hyperskill.org site and in my IDE I get what I expect but the site tells me "wrong answer"

Comment: I return now ArrayList converted to String array
public static String[] getFieldsContainingAnnotations(Object object) {
        Class cl = object.getClass();
        ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : cl.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getDeclaredAnnotations().length > 0) {
                fields.add(field.getName());
                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }
        }
        String[] retArray = GetStringArray(fields);
        return retArray;
    }

Comment: What are the exact requirements specified by hyperskill.org? Please [edit] your question to add that information rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: Implement the getFieldsContainingAnnotations method that lists the names of the fields declared in the object. The list should include all the fields containing at least one annotation. Fields inherited from parent classes should be omitted.

Comment: This is theory for the task. https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/8112

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Note you can do `return fields.toArray(new String[0])` to make conversion to an array easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908771/how-to-get-class-annotation-in-java